# Python defaults to wrong version; can't find scipy

Tags: scipy

I am new to python, hoping to use it for scientific computation, data acquisition, etc. My ignorance is near total.

I am using a macbook pro, running OSX 10.9.5.

I first installed python 2.7, numpy, and matplotlib; can't remember where they came from. They seem to sit in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework....

All was OK, until I realized I need scipy also.  So, I installed the entire scipy stack from scipy.org, using 'sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose', after having first installed xcode and the developer tools.

This new installation is located in \opt\local\var\macports\software...

Here's the question:  When I run python in a terminal, it always defaults to the original installation.  scipy, in particular, cannot be found.  I suppose this is a path problem, but I am out of my depth here.  Can someone help?

Comment: If you are totally new to python and need scientific packages, `anaconda` will probably be a very good option for you.

Comment: It's best to use [pip](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html), or even better [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), to install and manage module dependencies.